# Custom CSV Export - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, export

We need to create a custom CSV Magento 2 Export. In particular, we need to add a column (or an attribute in additional_attributes column) that indicate the attribute’s position inside the category it is inserted.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: a product can belong to several categories. It does appear your question requires a custom function. Can you specify whether the issue you have is adding the new column or finding a way to output the product category?

Answer (score 0):

ok, I have added a new product attribute that I named "test_category", then I associated this attribute to an attribute set. Finally, I edited a product with some data for this added attribute. 
--> with the above, I can see my new product added automatically in the additional_attribute column for the product export feature as long as the product has data for this attribute.
--> now in a second step, it seems your blocker is that you need to create a script that assigns category position to this product attribute.